# Trying to bulk update cases through finding them and profile

Tags: civicase

Steps to Replicate:

1. Find Cases
2. Select All cases
3. Choose update cases from task options
4. Choose profile to update

Hits an error with DB Error: syntax error, was able to replicate on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Note: Individual selection of cases works fine, CRM errors when trying update all the results.

Comment: What fields are in your profile in step 4? It works ok for me if I do e.g. status and subject.

Comment: All the case core and custom fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a core bug and have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23853) for the fix.